# Is there a way to use Custom Parameters of an Event as a metric in Facebook Analytics charts?

Tags: facebook-analytics

i am sending parameters with my custom event. I would like to demonstrate them as a metric in the graph charts. Is there a way to do that?

For example, when i send an event with additional parameters of secondValue, thirdValue.

[I would like to decide which value to use as a metric without being limited to these three metrics:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aXPH.png)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this currently. Your best bet is to send multiple events (firstEvent, secondEvent, thirdEvent) instead of multiple custom parameters (firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue) and use the valueToSum argument for each event.

Comment: That makes the facebook console so ugly. :( If there is no way, than we need to do that in this way. Thanks for the answer ;)